# How to detach/remove EBS volumes from AWS EMR using Terraform?

Tags: terraform

Currently in Terraform, ebs_config option is used to specify the size and number of EBS volumes to be attached to a instance group in EMR. When no ebs_config is specified a default of 32GB EBS volume is attached to the core node in addition to the root volume. My case is not to have any EBS volumes attached to the core node. How do I specify that in terraform ?

Currently I use the following code

```
  name           = "CoreInstanceGroup"
  instance_role  = "CORE"
  instance_type  = "m4.xlarge"
  instance_count = "1"
  ebs_config {
    size = 1
    type = "gp2"
    volumes_per_instance = 1
  }
```

Terraform doesn't allow size and volumes_per_instance to be 0.

Comment: Are you sure when `ebs_config` isn't specified, that both of the EBS volumes are attached to your core instance?

Comment: Yes. A default of 32 GB EBS is added to all my master, core and task instances

Comment: Just one Kirupa?

Comment: Yes Nate. One of 32gb EBS to each instance

Comment: At least one EBS volume needs to be attached as this will host the core OS and any supported tooling required for EMR nodes to operate as expected.

Comment: Not necessarily Nate. I was manually able to create EMR cluster through AWS console with no EBS storage volume attached to both Master and Core nodes. I can't just get this setup through Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out this is not a terraform issue but that's how AWS EMR works. When you specify 'EBS only' instance as instance type (say m2.4xLarge), EMR automatically attaches an EBS storage volume in addition to the Root volume. If you specify SSD type instead of 'EBS only' as instance type(say r3.Xlarge), EMR doesn't attach an extra EBS volume.